# How to do curl ntlm authentication with an xml response

Tags: authentication, curl, ntlm

I am trying to get a xml response from the server, but im getting this: SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate

Do you guys know how to proceed ?

```
$ curl http://example.com:86/DynamicsNAV80/WS/nasr/Page/Delivery -v --ntlm --negotiate -u nasr\\jason:tty5Rx53$_sj
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 21.55.152.170...
* Connected to example.com (21.55.152.170) port 86 (#0)
> GET /DynamicsNAV80/WS/nasr/Page/Delivery HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: example.com:86
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 0
* Server Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Date: Sun, 11 Mar 2018 23:20:34 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://example.com:86/DynamicsNAV80/WS/nasr/Page/Delivery'
* Found bundle for host example.com: 0x5558f1e0d4e0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host example.com
* Connected to example.com (21.55.152.170) port 86 (#0)
> GET /DynamicsNAV80/WS/nasr/Page/Delivery HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: example.com:86
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 0
* Server Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Date: Sun, 11 Mar 2018 23:20:34 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your curl version. I got the same issue previously (HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized). Once I upgraded the curl to 7.45.0 (or latest), the issue got resolved. Please go through the images below for better understanding.

Issue with the curl version 7.38.0. NTLM is disabled:
[image: Issue with the curl version 7.38.0. NTLM is disabled]

Issue resolved with the curl version 7.45.0. NTLM is enabled as well as some other parameters too.:
[image: Issue resolved with the curl version 7.45.0. NTLM is enabled as well as some other parameters too.]